# apt-file regex: find multiple packages at once using or

Tags: apt, regex, apt-file

I'd like to search multiple packages at one using a regexp connecting pattern with logical or `|`.

Assuming the two files `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp` and `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` exist:

```
$ sudo dpkg -S /usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
apache2-bin: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
$ sudo dpkg -S /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
apt: /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
```

why does `apt-file search --regexp '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp|/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily'` only return

```
apache2-bin: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
```

The solution is intended to be used for an [optimization of the GNOME build tool `jhbuild`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/jhbuild/merge_requests/5). It should work an a large set of Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is related to the source of files `apt-file` is matching. It uses the *Contents* files in */var/lib/apt/lists/*, which do not contain the leading `/`.

```
# lz4cat /var/lib/apt/lists/de.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_Contents-amd64.lz4 | grep httpd.exp
usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp               httpd/apache2-bin
usr/share/doc/lighttpd/expire.txt               universe/web/lighttpd-doc
```

So just skip the leading `/` in your regexp and you are fine. I also would recommend to escape dots `\.` since `.* only means to match any character. In this case it might give you the expected results, but only because there are no other matches.

```
# apt-file search --regexp 'usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd\.exp|usr/lib/apt/apt\.systemd\.daily'
apache2-bin: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp
apt: /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
```

---

The reason why it did work for `apache2-bin: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/httpd.exp` is because `apt-file` is taking care of leading slashes and removes them in the search pattern.

But this is only applied to the beginning of the pattern and it does not recognize the *or* operator and does not remove the leading slash from the *second* search part. The second search part `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily` does not match because of the missing leading slash in the *Contents* file.

---

Addendum

- as mentioned by N0rbert `apt-file --regexp` is using [Perl Regular Expressions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/perlreref.1.html)
- the relevant part from [man apt-file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) outlines the problem of this question in the *BUGS, QUIRKS* section

  > The Contents files do not include a leading slash on paths.  This means that /bin/ls is listed as bin/ls in the Contents file.  If you are looking for something in a top-level directory, it is often better to omit the leading slash.
  >
  > The search algorithm will attempt to work around the leading slash, but it will not work in all cases.  As
  >          a workaround, try to pull the leading slash to the beginning of regular expressions.  For example, use
  >          "/(?:usr/bin/vim|sbin/lvm)" instead of  "/usr/bin/vim|/sbin/lvm".

Comment: Great. Also please mention that `apt-file` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) says that it uses [Perl Regular Expressions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/perlreref.1.html).